State tomography in Qiskit on a subset of qubits of real QPU
Could anyone please explain how should I carry out a state tomography on a real device in Qiskit (version 0.43.2)?
I have access to devices with 127 qubits, but I want to perform a simulation using only four qubits and then do a state tomography on them. When I use StateTomography specifying the circuit, the backend and the measurement_indices, it just tries to evaluate the density matrix of the whole device (returning an error, since it would be $2^{127}\times2^{127}$). Is there any way to isolate just the four qubit I am working with?
